# iphone SDK download

Tags: iphone

Is there any difference(means full/limited access) in iphone SDK before and after enrolling in iPhone developer program ?

Thanking in Advaced...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no difference!

Just you won't be able to download beta versions of SDK's, if there're any.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to test on actual devices unless you enroll.